# How can I make a minecraft command block kill only aggressive mob

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I make a command block kill all aggressive mobs, and not passive ones?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can kill all aggressive mobs by setting the difficulty to peaceful.

```
/difficulty 0
```

Or you could `/kill @e[type=X]` where 'X' are mobs that are hostile.

```
/kill @e[type=cave_spider]
/kill @e[type=enderman]
and so on...
```

Comment: The command blocks would need to be set to repeat, and a locked circuit would have to be applied, unless the blocks are set to “Always Active”. Just for safety, set the area with the command blocks within it as a ticking area.

Answer (score -1):

There's an nbt called "anger", and you can put it in the selector like @e[nbt={anger:1}] or sth cuz im not very sure whether that is the correct value for aggression. And then just kill this type of entities

Comment: I am afraid that this answer is incorrect. Your answer only works in Java Edition. The question's [tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) clearly show the asker is playing in Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Oh! I thought in bedrock edition you can still detect the tag of Entities...... My fault.